# JavaScript form validation 2 letters 1 number

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a validation for my form with JavaScript. This is what I have done so far, and it works, but in the input "klassekode"  needs to start with two letters and then one number.

My html code

```
<form class="form1" method="POST" id="registrerFagSkjema" action="registrerklasse.php" name="registrerFagSkjema"  onSubmit="return validerRegistrerFag()">


        Registrer klasse  <br> <br>
        Klassekode <br>
        <input value="" type="text" name="fagkode" id="fagkode"  onFocus="fokus(this)"
                onBlur="mistetFokus(this)" onMouseOver="musInn(this)" onMouseOut="musUt()"
                onChange="endreTilStoreBokstaver(this)"/ /><br>

        Klassenavn <br>
        <input value="" type="text" name="klassenavn" id="klassenavn"   onFocus="fokus(this)"
                onBlur="mistetFokus(this)" onMouseOver="musInn(this)" onMouseOut="musUt()"  />

        
        <input value="Registrer Klasse" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" >
        <input type="reset" value="Nullstill" id="reset" name="reset" onClick="fjernMelding()">


</form>

 <div id="melding"></div>
```

My JavaScript code

```
function validate()

{
  var klassekode = document.getElementById("klassekode");
  var klassenavn = document.getElementById("klassenavn");
  var feilmelding="";
  //var firstTwoLetters = document.getElementById("klassekode").substring(0,2);

  if(klassekode.value.trim()=="")
  { 
    
    //alert("blank");
    feilmelding="Fyll ut Klassekode";
    document.getElementById("melding").style.color="red";
    document.getElementById("melding").innerHTML=feilmelding;

    klassekode.style.border = "solid 1px red";
    return false;
  }
  else if ( klassekode.value.trim().length!=3)
  {
    //alert("klassekode for lang");
    feilmelding="Klassekode må kun være 3 bokstaver";
    document.getElementById("melding").style.color="red";
    document.getElementById("melding").innerHTML=feilmelding;
    klassenavn.style.border = "solid 1px red";
    return false;
  }
  else if (klassenavn.value.trim()=="" )
  {
    //alert("blank");
    feilmelding="Fyll ut Klassenavn";
    document.getElementById("melding").style.color="red";
    document.getElementById("melding").innerHTML=feilmelding;
    klassenavn.style.border = "solid 1px red";
    return false;
  }
  else { return true;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the hang of substring, and you can use that the newer method `isNaN` (Not a Number) and divide your third character with 1. If it's a letter, `isNaN` will return "true" and if it's a number, it will return "false".

---

I would, however, recommend you to learn [regular expressions](https://regexr.com/), as it will benefit you tremendously in the future.

You basically create a pattern and then test a string against that pattern. If you find a match, then it's  correct. I made a snippet below to demonstrate:

```js
function validateInput() {
  let inputElement = document.getElementById("namn");
  let divElement = document.getElementById("comment");
  
  var message = "not true";
  let inputValue = inputElement.value.trim();
  
  let pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zøæ]{2}\d{1}/, "i");
  
  if (isValid(inputValue, pattern)) {
    message = "true"    
  }
  
  divElement.innerHTML = message;
}

function isValid(str, pattern) {
  return str.match(pattern);
}
```

```html
<input id="namn" type="input" value="">

<input type="button" onclick="validateInput()" value="Validate" />

<div id="comment"></div>
```

This row needs explanation:

`let pattern = new RegExp(/^\d{1}[a-zøæ]{2}/, "i");`

The regular expression contains expressions that can be stringed together:
^: start at the beginning of the string.
[a-zøæ]{2}: 2 characters must be between a-z or contain ø or æ.
\d{1}: next following 1 character must be a digit.

The flag "i" makes the a-z case insensitive. Another way would be to don't add a flag, and instead write [a-zA-ZøØæÆ]

Answer (score 0):

Regex to the rescue. You can add another `else if` statement as per the following:

```
else if (klassekode.value.trim().length !== 3) {
    // after checking whether the string length is 3 characters...
} else if (!klassekode.value.trim().match(/^[a-z]{2}\d/i)) {
    // apply validation warning styles
    return false;
}
```

An explanation of the Regex:
`^` - asserts position at the start of the string
`[a-z]` - matches an alphabetic character
`{2}` - matches exactly twice
`\d` - matches a digit (0-9) once
`i` - case insensitive match

I am not checking the string length again because your previous condition accounts for it.

Ensure to `trim()` the value before using it (e.g. before sending it to the backend for processing, etc.), because otherwise the leading/trailing spaces will be retained.